# Godaddy redirect doesn't show file names in URL

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect, godaddy

Bought a Godaddy doman and redirected & masked it (301) to a temporal free hosting site(freehostingeu), the redirection and masking works perfectly but the URL of the various pages in my server's folder doesn't show in the nav bar when I click a link that sends me to that page.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the GoDaddy redirect isnt a "real" redirect. It will just generate a file with frames and loads the target URL into that frame.

Thats why your URL at the top doesn't change. Look at the HTML source code and you will find the frameset.

Comment: This is correct for Forward with Masking, depending on the URL and target value, URLs can break out of the parent frame.

Comment: That's true. How do I get the sub files and folders to show in the URL then?